# how to import .txt to mysql file?

Tags: mysql, database

how to import .txt to mysql file?

I have a .txt file with hundreds of records and I want to import it into the mysql database table.

example:
**word.txt** contains data:

```
word_1
word_2
word_3
.
.
.
.
.
word_n
```

I have a table in the mysql database:
**tbl_word:**

```
field: id_word, value_word, create_date, update_date
```

value in every line of word.txt file will I insert / import to column value_word with setting id_word AUTO_INCREAMENT, how to do?

Comment: @Bradley-Coupland yes i use phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to import a file into a table

```
load data infile 'word.txt'
into tbl_word
fields
  terminated by '\t'
  lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 0 lines
(@c1,@c2,@c3,..,@cN)
set value_word=@c1;
```

id_word will increment automaticaly

Comment: no, N is the column count of your file to import  if word.txt has 1 column then what you need is `(@c1)`

Comment: error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual @guigoz there is mistake :  that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'tbl_word
fields
  terminated by '\t'
  lines terminated by '\n'

Comment: thanks, Your sintax is incomplete I add: INTO TABLE. complete syntax becomes: load data infile 'word.txt'
into TABLE tbl_word
fields
  terminated by '\t'
  lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 0 lines
(@c1,@c2,@c3,..,@cN)
set value_word=@c1;

Answer (score 0):

tbl_word _listData = new tbl_word();

string text = read all text from text file.

```
for (iterate till end of text )
{
if(line break logic)
var value = split line;
_listData.value_word = value;
insert into table tbl_word values will have var value;
}
```